# align justify in class def not working

Tags: html

I have what I am sure is a really obvious fix for a really simple problem, but I can't seem to see it. I am trying to define a `class` in my inline css that will generally be employed in `<span class="padl18">...</span>` tags to indent text by 18 as well a `text-align:justify` with:

```
.padl18{padding-left:18; text-align:justify;}
```

The indent works fine but the resulting text enclosed in the `span` tags aligns left rather than justifies.

Another one of my `class` definitions:

```
.pvi{margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; text-align:justify;}
```

does align justify, so I am not sure what the hitch might be, if anyone can help muchos gracias.

Comment: 18 *what*? `px`, `em`, `%`..?

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input "Value Error : padding-left only 0 can be a length. You must put a unit after your number : 18"

Comment: Well I think `px` defaults right? Regardless the indent part as I mentions works as expected, so no probs there (I did add `px` in my def just to be sure not adding did not adversely affect the def and it had no affect, so continuing on). The problem is trying to define a text justification for the text enclosed in `span` tags.

Comment: actually if I remove the `padding-left:18` altogether, leaving just the `text-indent:justify` in place, the spanned text still does not justify. Maybe the justify only works for text enclosed in `<p>...</p>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the issue. `text-align: justify` requires a block-level element with a fixed width. If you applying the class `padl18` to a `<span>` element it won't work.

So, to fix it you need to make your CSS look like this:

```
.padl118 {
    padding-left: 18px; /* must include a unit such as px */
    text-align: justify;
    display: block; /* a <span> is inline by default */
    width: 200px; /* set any width, such as 200px, 3em, 100% etc */
}
```

This JSFiddle shows that in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mm2xe/4/

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: that did it. Worked like a charm. I also realized it was actually `text-indent` and not `padding-left` which I wanted.

Comment: The `text-align` property applies to block containers only, so `display: block` is the answer. Setting a fixed width is irrelevant, because there is always some `width` value. The jsfiddle does not demonstrate anything unless you make the “Result” window very narrow – the text is so short that it normally fits on one line.